# transformer.transform doesn't work with URL?

Tags: java, xml, servlets

So I am trying to run a web application that gets user input from an HTML form and appends it to an XML document on the server using Java Servlets.

Here is how I get the XML file and modify it.

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
{
     try {
          String urlpath = "http://192.168.11.9:8080/Chat-sort-of/Messages.xml";
          DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
          URL url = new URL(urlpath);
          HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

          urlc.setDoInput(true);
          urlc.setDoOutput(true);
          urlc.setUseCaches(false);
          urlc.setRequestMethod("GET");
          urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application / xml");

          Document doc = docBuilder.parse(urlc.getInputStream());
          Node m = doc.getElementsByTagName("messages").item(0);
          Element messageNode = doc.createElement("message");
          testMessage = request.getParameter("message-box");
          if(testMessage == null) {response.sendRedirect("http://192.168.11.9:8080/Chat-sort-of/index.html");}
          messageNode.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(testMessage));
          m.appendChild(messageNode);
```

Here is how I write to the XML file:

```
if(urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
              urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              urlc.setDoOutput(true);
              urlc.setUseCaches(false);
              urlc.setRequestMethod("POST");
              urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application / xml");

              TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
              transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
              Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
              DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
              StreamResult result = new StreamResult(urlc.getOutputStream());
              transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
              transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM,"");
              transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");                
              transformer.transform(source, result);
          }
      }catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
       }
      response.sendRedirect("http://192.168.11.9:8080/Chat-sort-of/index.html");
}
```

No errors during compilation.

If I replace the variable "result" with System.out in the transformer.transform function, the program prints the XML file correctly and with the modification, meaning that the source isn't empty.

I know that this isn't the best way to do this, but I wouldn't do any other way right now.

Any ideas?

Comment: please clarify your question, what you are seeing and what you expect to see.

Comment: I am expecting the XML file to change. And I am seeing no change.